# Accessing your Main Activity from another package

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, main-activity

I am using **libGDX**. Created a project and there are two packages as **appName**, **appName-android**. My codes are in **appName**, but **MainActivity.java** is in the **appName-android** package. I set the admob advertise in the MainActivity but i don't want to have it always visible.

The question is, how can i edit adView.VISIBLE from another package? Or is it possible? How can i access MainActivity.java(in **appName-android** package) from a class in **appName** package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post some code to make the issue more clear. What you've described is a sign of a bad design, but at the moment there's not enough information to figure things out.

Comment: But i cannot see which code i should send. Because the problem is not "where am i wrong". This is the standard construction of libGDX. If you create a project with gdx-setup-ui.jar, it creates packages like project, project-android, project-desktop and project-html. You write your codes in project, and it creates applications for all platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way (in libGDX) to access platform-specific code (like Android adMob libraries) from your platform-independent common code is to create an interface that your common code can use, and implement the platform specific bits in an implementation of that interface.

So, create `public interface AdControlInterface` that contains a method like `hideAds` or whatever you want.  Have the **appName-android** package create an Android-specific implementation of that interface and pass it into the **appName** package (via the constructor on the `ApplicationListener` subclass you have in **appName** package).

Here's a tutorial on AdMob in libGDX that covers this issue (see the `IActivityRequestHandler` interface) and some of the other adMob integration issues: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/AdMobInLibgdx

Comment: I looked this tutorial before but after your answer, i looked more carefully and yes, it shows (at least gives inspire) something about the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use those kind of tools, unfortunately, you can't change somethings.

There's no way to change the way how android deal with the access to the main package. You may create static methos to access some code without instance, but I really think is not a good idea..